# MVC-Multiple button handling in loop

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following View

```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('#arrows').click(function () {

            switch(document.getElementById("arrows").className) {
                case 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right':
                    document.getElementById("arrows").className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom';
                   // $('#comments').css({ display: "block" });

                    break;
                case 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom':
                    document.getElementById("arrow").className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right';
                    //$('#comments').css({display:"none"});
                    break;
            }
        });
       });

<ul class="mar">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                <li class="mar" style="list-style-type:none">
                    <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:small">

                            <a id="arrows" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right style="text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;color:dimgray"></a>

                        <h3 class="mar" style="display:inline-block;">@Html.ActionLink(item.thread.Title, "GetMessage", "Home")</h3>
                    </div>
```

Here arrow changed  for the first item..Other arrows for the items doesnot change..I have searched lot in the web,but didnt find the solution..Could anyone help me out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html and `getElementById("arrows")` will only ever return the first element in the DOM with `id="arrows"`.

Change your code to use class names

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    ....
    <a class="arrows" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" ... ></a>
    ....
}
```

and the script will be

```
$('.arrows').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-triangle-right')) {
        $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-right').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting the element with id=1

try
    if ($(this).find('#1').css('display') != 'none') {
                    $(this).find('#2').html('Here is my dynamic content').show().siblings('div').hide();